# is there a way to ask supervisor to source vars from a file?

Tags: bash, supervisord

I have a supervisor conf file that need a lot of environment variables::

```
$ cat /etc/supervisor/conf.d/aaa_staging.conf 
[program:aaa_staging]
environment=
    API_HOST="https://aaa-api-staging.zettauser.com/api/",
    CLOUD_INSTANCE_NAME=media-server-xx-xx-xx-xx,
    CLOUD_APPLICATION=media-server,
    CLOUD_APP_COMPONENT=none,
    CLOUD_ZONE=a,
    CLOUD_REGION=b,
    CLOUD_PRIVATE_IP=none,
    CLOUD_PUBLIC_IP=xx.xx.xx.xx,
    CLOUD_PUBLIC_IPV6=xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx,
    CLOUD_PROVIDER=c
command=/opt/aaa-staging/bin/gunicorn 'aaa.app:app' --workers 4 --bind 0.0.0.0:5046 --timeout 1200
user=user
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
directory=/opt/aaa-staging/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/aaa/
stdout_logfile=/var/log/aaa-staging_app
$
```

Variables originaly live in a conf file::

```
$ cat /etc/aaa.conf
API_HOST="https://aaa-api-staging.zettauser.com/api/"
CLOUD_INSTANCE_NAME=media-server-xx-xx-xx-xx
CLOUD_APPLICATION=media-server
CLOUD_APP_COMPONENT=none
CLOUD_ZONE=a
CLOUD_REGION=b
CLOUD_PRIVATE_IP=none
CLOUD_PUBLIC_IP=xx.xx.xx.xx
CLOUD_PUBLIC_IPV6=xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx
CLOUD_PROVIDER=c
$
```

Is there a way to inform `supervisor` about the fact it has to *source*
Variables from `/etc/aaa.conf` ?

Comment: no -c is for the full configuration file I talk about the specific `environment=` part of the configuration file

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/242) thread.